# JSF 2 - Change the content of a tab

Tags: jsf-2, tabs

I'm starting to work with JSF2. I've chosen the framework called OpenFaces although I don't mind to use another framework as RichFaces.

In both frameworks there is a component to render tabs.

```
<o:tabbedPane id="tabbedPane" ... >
   <o:subPanel caption="#{msg['app.welcome.caption.title']}">
        ... SOME JSF CONTENT ...
   </o:subPanel>
   <o:subPanel caption="#{msg['app.search.caption.title']}"> 
      <h:panelGroup id="searchPanelGroup" layout="block">
        ... A JSF SEARCH FORM ...
      </h:panelGroup>
   </o:subPanel> 
</o:tabbedPane>
```

The second tab has a search form. What I would like is that when a user press the search buttom, and after the search is done, the search form would be replaced by the search results with for example a  tag. This  tag would be defined in a different XHTML file.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to include those two files in your tab

Comment: Just a small comment: do you know about PrimeFaces? It's much easier and full of features than any other JSF library, thus making your life easier as a beginner. ;)

Comment: When you say to include those two files in the tab, what do you refer? My tab is initially loaded with one file, and after a submit, I want the same tab load the second file, painting the search results without painting the search form.

Comment: I've heard about PrimeFaces, but even with this framework, I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Eduardo.... If you show what you tried and how you tried here,It would be helpful to answer. If you explain like this,users here won't get interest to answer you question?So, please post some code to your explanation.

Comment: I hope I have explained a little bit better now